# When I run scrollintoview in Safari, the element disappears from the screen

Tags: javascript, scroll, safari, scrollview

I am currently developing in the next.js environment.

```
useEffect(() => {
  topCardRef.current?.scrollIntoView();
}, [data]);
```

As in the code above, it was implemented to scroll when there is a change in data.

In Chrome, it works as expected, but in Safari, the scrolling element is not displayed on the screen after the function is executed.

Elements that disappear from the screen appear again when the user scrolls.

Did I give you the wrong options?

I would like to know how to prevent elements from disappearing from the screen after running scrollintoview.